# Windows 10 command prompt shows plain color codes instead of applying them

Tags: windows, colors, cmd

I have searched a lot (but I might have missed, though) and didn't find any solution because mostly the questions are about specific programming language (like with C++).

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit and I'm working with Windows console. Programs and functions (that display results) display in console only and by default they insert color codes. **But in console I see plain color codes instead of seeing colorful text itself.** It looks both dull (with one color) and messy. I know it's possible to somehow change this because in other computer it works (and using same OS).

A screenshot how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, for example, on the first line, it shows something like: `[1mFunctional Tests (1) [22m-` but it is supposed to apply colors (blue/green/red, etc.). I'm not sure what other information I need to add so please ask if something else is needed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Make sure that in the console options "use legacy console" is unchecked (I'm not a Windows 10 box now so I can't check if that really helps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see you are using Win10 already. On at least Windows 10 **TH2** or older, I believe you need uncheck 'Use Legacy Console' in command prompt properties as Christian.K said.

---

Simply, Windows doesn't support console colors using Color Escape ASCII `\033` **until Windows 10 TH2 10586**. For Windows console program, it is more difficult to get some characters in a different color. You need to achieve the goal by this:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
std::cout << "No-color here!\n" << std::flush;
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, <someColorCode>);
std::cout << "Color here!\n" << std::flush;
```

Colors are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes).

Comment: But the OP explicitly says he's using Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see it.

Comment: But is there anything I can change (in registry, for example), that I would see console with color codes applied to text or it is not possible at all? (I'll assume other computer uses something similar as a replacement)

Comment: @EdvinTenovim Which build number of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @KeyuGan I'm using 10240

Comment: I believe it is a feature in Windows 10 10586 (TH2)

Comment: Hmm, understood. Thanks. I'll see if I can do anything to solve that.

Comment: There is a cmd wrapper called ANSICON which inteprets control codes correctly.